# How to make pythontex see PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, linux, latex, tex

I've been working with `pythontex` for some time and I'm quite happy with the results. After reinstalling the system, however, serious difficulties began.

**THE PROBLEM**: while compiling code (in .tex documents) and trying to *import local modules* I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'm_system'` (the offending line: `import m_system`; I listed `sys.path` in a .tex document and it has no idea about the contents of `PYTHONPATH` system variable).

I cannot remember how I got it working the previous time, but it worked just fine. I was searching for an answer, grilling ChatGPT -- to no avail.

How could I solve it? Make `PYTHONPATH` the same for `pythontex`?

The new system:

- Linux Mint 21.3, Cinnamon 64-bit
- `tex` → `TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)`
- editor: sublime-text 4169

The system allows for compilation of pdf documents, along with python code inside. This snippet returned appropriate message in the pdf:

```
\begin{pycode}
import sys

print(f"{sys.version = }")
\end{pycode}
```

The result was `sys.version = ’3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]’` (in the pdf).

What other pieces of information could provide additional, necessary details?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: in `.bashrc`: `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/softdev/python/lib`; in the `lib` folder there are all the modules of the library

Comment: How are you running your latex build system? Do note that `.bashrc` is only read when you start a (non-login) interactive bash shell. In order for that file to have any effect, you'd need to run your latex build commands manually from an interactive bash shell (or from some other inheriting process). In particular, that file generally won't have any effect on GUI LaTeX editors or IDE build systems.

Comment: In this case where should I put `PYTHONPATH` config, so it would affect running `pythontex` from within sublime-text? .profile invokes `.bashrc`, putting export of `PYTHONPATH` into `.profile` won't help, right? Where then?